# Generating many tables from a single table in SAS

Tags: sas, code-generation, binning

I have a table in SAS which contains the format information I want. I want to bin this data into the categories given.

What I don't know how to do is create either an xform or a format file from the data.

An example table looks like this:

```
     TxtLabel  Type FmtName label   Hlo count
         .      I   FAC1f    0      O    1
        1996    I   FAC1f    1           2
        1997    I   FAC1f    2           3
```

I want to date all years in a different data set as after 1997 OR before 1996.

The problem is that I know how to do this by hard coding it, but these files changes the numbers each time so I'm hoping to use the information in the table to generate the bins rather than hard code them.

How do I go about binning by data using a column from another dataset for my categorization?

**Edit**

I have two data sets, one which looks like the one I have included and one which has a column titled "YEAR". I want to bin the second data set using the categories from the first. In this case there are two available years in TxtLabel. There are multiple tables like this, I'm looking at how to generate PROC Format code from the table, rather than hard coding the values.

Comment: Hello, Can You add example what you mean in "...date all years..."? thx

Comment: You can generate a format using CNTLIN on PROC FORMAT but you haven't shown a clear definition of what you're trying to do. Since you have HLO in the data set it appears it's set up to use PROC FORMAT. To make it work you'd need to add the start/end variable but that's pretty trivial.

Comment: "using a column from another dataset" is generally another way of saying "control table" for some process.  What is the structure of this other table and what values would be found in it ?  Add the information to your question (don't put the info in a comment)

Comment: **I know how to do this by hard coding...** - show your code for one case, so we know what you know.  Then generalization can follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should run to create the desired format

```
Proc FORMAT CNTLIN=MyCustomFormatControlData;
run;
```

You can then use it in a DATA Step, or apply it to a column in a data set.

Binning the data might be construed as 'data set splitting' but your question does not make it clear if that is so.  Generic arbitrary splitting is often done with one of these techniques:

- wall paper source code resolved from macro variables populated from information garnered in a `Proc SQL` or `Proc FREQ` step
- dynamic data splitting using `hash` object for grouping records in memory, and saved to a data set with an `.output()` call.

Sample code for explicit binning

```
data want0 want1 want2 want3 want4 want5 wantOther;
  set have;
  * explicit wall paper;
  select (put(year,FAC1f.));
    when ('0') output want0;
    when ('1') output want1;
    when ('2') output want2;
    when ('3') output want3;
    when ('4') output want4;
    when ('5') output want5;
    otherwise output wantOther;
run;
```

This is the construct that source code generated by macro can produce, and requires

- one pass to determine the `when/output` lines that are to be generated
- a second pass to apply the lines of code that were generated.

If this is the data processing that you are attempting:

- do some research (plenty of info out there)
- write some code
- make a new question if you get errors you can't resolve

**Proc FORMAT**

[`Proc FORMAT` has a `CNTLIN` option](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=p0owa4ftikc2ekn1q0rmpulg86cx.htm&locale=en#p05g1cdvff8h8tn1frtzxrnkzezo) for specifying a data set containing the format information. The structure and values expected of the Input Control Data Set (that CNTLIN) is described in the [Output Control Data Set](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p0owa4ftikc2ekn1q0rmpulg86cx.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p1pm9xy2v45zhrn1y16e6nzor0qr) documentation.  Some of the important control data columns are:

> FMTNAME
>   specifies a character variable whose value is the format or informat name.
>
> LABEL
>   specifies a character variable whose value is associated with a format or an informat.
>
> START
>   specifies a character variable that gives the range's starting value.
>
> END
>   specifies a character variable that gives the range's ending value.

As the requirements of the custom format to be created get more sophisticated you will need to have more *information variables* in the input control data set.

Comment: This ended up solving my problem, but it took me a little time to get it. I have a follow up question: Can you store more than one format in a single CNTLOUT? The first column FMTNAME seems to imply you can have two formats in one file, but when I tried to build it and use CNTLIN it failed?

Comment: A follow up question should be posted as a new question (with a reference to the prior one). As usual, include code and error/warning/note messages; but yes `CNTLOUT=` will output format data of more than one custom format, and `CNTLIN=` can specify format data that contains more than one format.

Comment: For some reason it needs manually refreshing before those formats appear in my working directory, I assumed this was close enough of a sub-question to not require it's own. Possibly not.